# How to print all characters by their index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Just for exercising with `indexOf()` method and to have a better familiarity with how it works and what can be done with it, I desire to print the index for each character in a phrase, one by one.

I could do it successfully manually, this way:

```
// Print index for char of phrase (case insensitive):

let phrase = "ab";

alert(phrase.indexOf("a")); // 0
alert(phrase.indexOf("b")); // 1
alert(phrase.indexOf("z")); // -1
```

But when I tried to use a loop, I failed:

```
// Print char by index:

let phrase = "ab";

for (let i = -1; i < phrase.indexOf(); i++) {
    alert(phrase.length[i]);
}
```

I also tried with regex to target each character inside `phrase` but also failed:

```
let phrase = "ab";

for (let i = -1; i < phrase.indexOf(/./); i++) {
    alert(phrase.length[i]);
}
```

To clarify, my aim is to have a first alert with `0`, and the second with `1`. I just want to print the index of each character, instead the character length, as can easily be done with:

```
phrase.length // 2.
```

How could I print the index of each character in separate alerts?

It is super important for me to use `indexOf()` inside a loop to know this syntax.

Comment: What do you think `i < phrase.indexOf()` or `phrase.length[i]` means? Your code makes no sense.

Comment: `"abcdef".split("").forEach(char => console.log(char, phrase.indexOf(char))`. and don't use `alert`s for debugging. EVERY semi-modern browser has very powerful dev-tools and a console that can deal with way more *(arguments and types)* than a single String.

Comment: @SLaks I thought that `i < phrase.indexOf()` will target all characters (given no specific character was given). I understand it will never do that. Regarding `phrase.length[i]` I tried to use the length as a collection of characters to go on, but I understand this was a mistake as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the index of each character in a loop you don't need `indexOf()`

```
let phrase = "ab";
for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    alert (i);
}
```

because `i` is the exact index you need.

In fact if you use `indexOf()` in a loop, that's what it looks like :

```
let phrase = "ab";
for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    alert (phrase.indexOf (phrase[i]));
}
```

Same result as before, but this time, instead of displaying `i`, you retrieve the current element in `phrase` and use `indexOf()` to get the already known index.

EDIT : `indexOf()` in this case work as expected because letters in `phrase` are different. But as SamVK said if `let phrase = "banana";`, it can't work because it will return always `1` for letter 'a' so you must not use it for that kind of loop.

I did not use `let i = -1` because it is not an index of `phrase`. It is just what `indexOf()` returns if it can't find the element given.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `indexOf`. You use this method to get the position (index) of a certain character in the string:

A string has a length property and can be iterated:

```js
let phrase = "aaabbbaaaabbb"

function getAllIndices(stringInput) {

  for (let i = 0; i < stringInput.length; i++) {
  //you simply need to output i.
      console.log(stringInput[i] + " > " + i);
  }
}

getAllIndices(phrase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way :

```
for(let i=0; i<phrase.length; i++) {
    console.log(phrase.indexOf(phrase[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While not always the case: the most common format for a `for` loop is:

`for (let i = 0; i < someVariable.length; i++) { //...some code }`

And indeed that's what you want here.

It means:

- start at i being 0 (`i = 0`)
- Do whatever is in my body (`// ...some code`)
- increase i by 1 (`i++`)
- Repeat, until i is equal to one less than the length of someVariable (`someVariable.length`) *

* That last step may seem kinda confusing. Remember: indices start at 0, but length count, well, counts normal - so starting at 1. So an string of length 3, say 'c'+'a'+'t'. is made up of characters at indices [0, 1, 2]. Sooo you want the loop, to stop at that last index - 2 - which is (always) one *less* that the length. (But honestly, this is overexplaining it. The short answer is: if you wanna loop through something - 99 times out of 100 you want that exact `for loop` format given up top.

---

So to look at your example: we wanna fix three things:

- We want to have `let i = 0;` (remember it doesn't increment until it's run once
- We want to say `i < phrase.length;` (`i < phrase.indexOf()` doesn't mean anything. `phrase.indexOf()` is a function, not a number.)
- `phrase.length` means "tell me the length of the variable phrase." It just returns a number. (So `phrase.length[i]` doesn't mean anything). If you want to alert whatever letter is at this index, it's just `phrase[i]`. *

* If this syntax for getting a letter by just putting [#] after strings seems weird - well that's because it was more designed for arrays . If you have `let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, then sure, I could see why the JavaScript devs said "let's make a quick way to get, oh, the value at index 2 of an array. How about just `arr[2]`? But for consistency, they said "yeah sure, let's give this ability to strings to." And if you think about it, a string *is* sort of just an array of letters.

---

*Update:* I just noticed you wanted the *index* of each letter, not the letter itselt. Well...technically you could just `alert(i)` then. That's it, that's the index. But if you wanted to know *what* letter we're talking about, I would do something like `alert("Letter " +  phrase[i] + " is at index " + i)`

---

**So our final answer is:**

```
let phrase = "ab";

for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    alert("Letter " +  phrase[i] + " is at index " + i)
}
```

---

---

> It is super important for me to use `indexOf()` inside a loop to know this syntax.

You would never use `indexOf()` for something like this. It would not just be unnecessary, it would be wrong. If you had the string `banana` and tried to use `indexOf()` to (re)check each letters position, you would get `0,1,2,1,2,1`. Why? Because `indexOf()` only returns the index of the *first* instance of that letter.

`indexOf()` is not something you'd likely pair with a for loop - at least not a for loop searching the same string. It is a loop itself. It's job is to *prevent* you from having to write a for loop to find the index of "b" in "ab". It will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to use indexOf in a loop, you could do so :

```js
let phrase = "ab";

Array.from(phrase).forEach(char => {
  console.log(phrase.indexOf(char))
})
```

But this is pretty useless as there are simpler ways to accomplish this but since it looks like it is for a learning purpose, I hope this answer helps you!